# Pass Values to Web Api URL in Query string C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I am new to Web API and need to pass values dynamically  from UI(Windows Application) in `URL` as posted below with value parameters in Bold.

```
URL:http://openbasket-quote.sit.svc/v3/allQuotes/**{number}**/version/**{version}**?format=OrderGroupXml&country=**{country}**&ignoreExpirationDate=true
```

**i have done in this way.**

```
string eQuoteURL = eTempQuoteURL + eQuoteNo + "/" + "version" + "/" + versionNo + "?" + "format=OrderGroupXml&country=" + country + "&ignoreExpirationDate=true";
```

Is there any other way to pass values to `URL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a composite format string:

```
string eQuoteURL = string.Format("{0}{1}/version/{2}?
  format=OrderGroupXml&country={3}&ignoreExpirationDate=true", 
    eTempQuoteURL, 
    eQuoteNo, 
    versionNo, 
    country);
```

In C# 6, you can use an interpolated string:

```
string eQuoteURL = $"{eTempQuoteURL}{eQuoteNo}/version/
    {versionNo}?format=OrderGroupXml&country={country}&ignoreExpirationDate=true";
```

Or you could use a library like [Flurl](https://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/) or [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/).